# how to catch value of the $scope model object being $watched

Tags: angularjs

in my angular app, I have a model object 'selectedDcName'
the value of this model is associated with the selection made in a drop-down select
I'm trying to $watch for the value change, and I need to know what the new value actually is.

How to do this properly?

Here is my html markup:

```
 <isteven-multi-select
                                        input-model="dcNames"
                                        output-model="selectedDcName"
                                        button-label="icon name"
                                        item-label="icon name maker"
                                        tick-property="ticked"
                                        selection-mode="single"
                                        >
                                </isteven-multi-select>
```

And here is the controller:

```
$scope.selectedDcName='';

        $scope.$watch('selectedDcName', function(name) {
            console.log('new selectedDcName value: ' + name);
        });
```

Contrary to my expectations, 'name' has nothing in it.

How do I do this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/gpmBqd

This is the code I wrote for the same purpose. It splits all of the duties apart into a service, a controller for the data, and a directive for the dom manipulation.

Check out how simple!:

```
;(function AngularSelectbox() {
  "use strict";
  var SelectBox = angular.module('selectbox', []);
  SelectBox.service('SelectboxUtils', function() {
    this.getStates = function() {
      var statesOpts = {
        // $http.post(..., function())...
        "options": ['Florida', 'Georgia', 'Alabama', 'New York'],
      };
      return statesOpts;
    };
  }).controller('statesDataCtrl', function($scope, SelectboxUtils) {
      $scope.selectbox = {};
      $scope.selectbox.optionsVisible = false;
      $scope.selectbox.selectorSrc = 'http://placehold.it/20x20/';
      $scope.selectbox.options = SelectboxUtils.getStates().options;
      $scope.selectbox.placeholder = 'Please make a selection';
      $scope.selectbox.selected = $scope.selectbox.placeholder; // Always will pull the first option as the default
  }).directive('selectbox', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, elm) {
        $scope.activateSelection = function(selection, index) {
          $scope.selectbox.selected = selection;
          $scope.selectbox.selectedIndex = index;
        };
        $scope.toggleOpts = function() {
          $scope.selectbox.optionsVisible = !$scope.selectbox.optionsVisible;
        };
      }
    };
  });
})();
```

Comment: Also worth noting that by splitting your Angular modules up like this will have you reusing code you never thought you could re-use ... over and over again! I used a TrackActiveSelection service about a dozen times over the course of a small app a have recently developed, for the navigation menu, image slider, for the accordion. AngularJS is really something else.

Comment: this is nice! however, in my app, i'm using this third-party 'isteven-multi-select', which outputs its selection to a model named selectedDcName. I'm trying to figure out how to catch the actual value once it is changed. this would apply to any other model being watched. the function, associated with $watch fires fine, but I do not know how to get the changed value

Comment: Ahh, I see I thought you made the custom istevenselect thing yourself. I wish I could be of more assistance, Im sure someone else has the goods for ya! I would say that instead of $watch in the controller (almost always a no-no), I would use ngChange as seen here in this tutorial http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) {return  $scope.selectedDcName },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue[0]){
            console.log('new value:  ' + newValue[0].name);
        }

        if(newValue[0]){
            $scope.$parent.selectedName = newValue[0].name;
        }

    }
);
```